# ORA-00904: invalid identifier in Oracle SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am probably messing something up between Oracle and MySQL  and since I am new to this, cant reallly figure out.
I have one table

```
CREATE TABLE Patient_Dtls(
    Patient_ID varchar2(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    First_Name varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
    Last_Name varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
    Contact_Number INT,
    Gender char(1),
    check(Gender in ('M', 'F'))
    );
```

and another table

```
CREATE TABLE Claim_Dtls(
    Claim_ID varchar2(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    Patient_ID varchar2(10) references Patient_Dtls(Patient_ID) ,
    Hospital_ID varchar2(10) references Hospital_Dtls(Hospital_ID),
    Amount_Submitted NUMBER(10,2) NOT NULL,
    Amount_Approved NUMBER(10,2),
    Status varchar2(20)
    check(Status in ('Submitted', 'Approved'))
```

and my question is:
Write a select query to view the claim and patient details  for the given patient id

the query I am using is:

```
Select * from Patient_Dtls,Claim_Dtls 
INNER JOIN Claim_Dtls 
    ON Patient_Dtls.Patiend_ID = Claim_Dtls.Patient_ID 
where Patient_ID = 111
```

sorry If its a baseless question.looking forward to the help

Comment: 'If you mix comma joins with the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of the form Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause' may occur' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html - you have invoked claim_dtls twice

Comment: And never use `SELECT *`. Just name (and qualify) just the columns you want returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some issues:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Patient_Dtls                          /*, no comma, just ANSI syntax */
       /*Claim_Dtls      <-- remove it */
       INNER JOIN Claim_Dtls
          ON Patient_Dtls.Patient_ID = Claim_Dtls.Patient_ID /* fix the column name*/
 WHERE Patient_Dtls.Patient_ID = 111            /* add the table identifier */
```

Also, you may find useful to use table aliases:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Patient_Dtls P
       INNER JOIN Claim_Dtls C
          ON P.Patient_ID = C.Patient_ID
 WHERE P.Patient_ID = 111
```